# Latex - table not showing

Tags: r, latex, tabular

I have seen several discussions on this board treating the topic but none of the solutions seem to work. I use R stargazer and have downloaded a table under Latex format, but when I copy paste the TeX code in my Latexfile, it does not show up in the PDF. I have also tried to use \input{myfile} with the table but the results is the same. Please find below a shorter version of the table. Does anybody have a solution ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Median} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
total\_asset & 10 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 50.000 & 5,556.000 \\ 
EBITDA\_margin & 6 & $-$5 & 12 & $-$1,250.000 & $-$0.085 & 0.1 & 0.033 & 42,500.000 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Kind regards,

Comment: The code you show in your question works ok(ish) for me. It is too wide to fit in the available space, but it definitely does show up in the document. Can you show your .log file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz actually it is too long for the whole program apparently, which part of it do you need ?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz when I try to run the table standalone I find : Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Test".tex

Comment: Can you share the .log file with https://pastebin.com/ or a similar service?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No idea why but now for the whole document, the Log files shows : Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Artcile_v2".tex

Comment: OK, let's try to figure this out first: which tex distribution do you have (texlive? miktex?), which editor do you use (texstudio, texmaker, etc?) and which operating system do you use?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use Miktex and Texmaker :) and Windows for the operating system

Comment: I'm neither a texmaker nore windows user, but I would first try to shut down and restart. if this does not help, check in the texmaker preferences if the paths to pdflatex etc are correct.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you, it did not work, so I uninstalled Texmaker and Miktex and reinstalled them and now it works. However as you mentioned this is too big for the page, I have to work on this now !

Comment: As a first step to make the table fit better, I would remove the extracolsep

Comment: Have you considered to exchange rows and columns?